# Is it possible to calculate a degree in css with vw?

Tags: css, sass, skew, degrees, css-calc

I'm trying to make my Skew responsive with view-width.

`$SkewXBar: calc(5deg + 10vw);`

I've searched online already, but found nothing regarding calculating a degree with vw.

If somebody knows an alternative, I'd be pleased to know.

Comment: if we forget about CSS a moment, how would you define the relation between Degree and vw?

Comment: also share your use case because I am pretty sure this an X/Y problem and you are searching the wrong way to solve it

Comment: `scew()` only accepts deg which is 360 of them in a polygon...vw is length -- apples and oranges. Instead of vw do you mean to just use a percent like `calc(5deg * 110%)`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A quick thought. The simplest way would be using a JavaScript logic. Something like the following:

```js
function calculate() {
  const deviceWidth = screen.width;
  const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const currentRatio = viewportWidth / deviceWidth;
  const angle = currentRatio * 360;
  document.querySelector('.rotating-bar').style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', calculate);
```

... which assumes an HTML structure like the following:

```html
<div class="rotating-bar">
  This rotates
</div>
```

CodePen example at https://codepen.io/baadaa/full/MWYMLwE